# GeoServer SQL View with integer param error

Tags: geoserver

Any reasons why the following query fails in GeoServer v2.23.1 SQL View?

```
select 1=%d%

ERROR: syntax error at or near ")" Position: 29
```

Here is the log message from PostgreSQL 14.5:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")" at character 29
STATEMENT:  select * from (select 1=%d%
    ) as "vtable" where 1 = 0
```

And here is the stack trace from GeoServer log:

```
18 июн. 18:29:09 INFO   [geoserver.web] - Error testing SQL query
java.io.IOException: Error occurred building feature type
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.buildFeatureType(JDBCFeatureSource.java:379)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.createFeatureSource(JDBCDataStore.java:906)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getFeatureSource(ContentDataStore.java:338)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getFeatureSource(ContentDataStore.java:308)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getSchema(ContentDataStore.java:294)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.createVirtualTable(JDBCDataStore.java:328)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.SQLViewAbstractPage.testViewDefinition(SQLViewAbstractPage.java:375)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.SQLViewAbstractPage$9.onClick(SQLViewAbstractPage.java:343)
    at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerAjaxFormLink.onSubmit(GeoServerAjaxFormLink.java:45)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxSubmitLink$1.onSubmit(AjaxSubmitLink.java:111)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior$AjaxFormSubmitter.onSubmit(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:218)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:787)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:174)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:601)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doPost(WicketServlet.java:159)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1656)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.HTTPMethodFilter.doFilter(HTTPMethodFilter.java:36)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:194)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:97)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilterInternal(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
  Позиция: 29
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:333)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:319)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:295)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:244)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getColumnMetadata(JDBCFeatureSource.java:871)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.buildFeatureType(JDBCFeatureSource.java:197)
    ... 151 more
```

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Have added the stack trace.

Comment: Not sure what a veiw of 1=? does, maybe you need to create a better query

Comment: That is just an example of a query with an integer parameter. My actual query is `select geom from g where id=%id%`. It used to work in v2.14.2 but after upgrade to the latest version it started throwing that error. If the param is a string, then the validation succeeds: `select '1'='%d%'`.

Comment: Please show the actual SQL that is failing along with the error from PostgreSQL along with the GeoServer log showing the query being sent to PostGreSQL

Comment: @IanTurton, I'm not trying to execute the query. What I do is just put that query into a new SQL View form in the admin panel, click Save and it failes to validate it with the issue reported. And there is nothing else in the logs apart from the bits provided, really.

Comment: Creating a view takes a valid query, the query in your question is invalid

Comment: What is wrong with this query: `select geom from g where id=%id%` ? It fails with the same error.

Comment: The postgis error is `select * from (select 1=%d%
    ) as "vtable" where 1 = 0` - of that `select 1=%d%` is your contribution and it is invalid

Comment: Ok. Here is the postgis error for the latter query: `select * from (select geom from g where id=%id%     ) as "vtable" where 1 = 0`. Does it make any difference?

Comment: works on my machine - what do you do to generate the error?

Comment: Nothing special. Just paste that query and click Save. If I roll back to v2.14.2 it works correctly while PostgreSQL db remains the same. The only difference I can think of is the Java version. I had the older GS version running on jre-8u341 while the newer one is on liberica-17.0.7.  There is also a problem starting GS service with the newer version btw (it just hangs in starting state), so I start it manually.

Comment: I'm on windows 10 machine if it matters.

Comment: Java 17 is not currently supported on OS that the devs use, so you are twice out of luck. Try with Java 11

Comment: Just to check something really silly - you did supply a default values didn't you?

Comment: Oh man! That is it! I had it defined in the older version config but missed it here. It really hard to find it out from that error message. Also a string param like in `'id'='%id%'` does not require any default value, which adds up to the confusion as well. Thanks!